# Apache Drill JSON Query Performance

Tags: apache-drill

I need help in trying to improve the performance of running aggregation queries of json.

My simple `count(*)` aggregation queries over json are taking 11 minutes to complete over only 640MB of data.

I have a single node cluster (8 cores, 8GB ram, using local SSD storage).

Data stats:

- 163,783 json files
- 640MB total

From the drill UI I can see the following:

> ```
> DURATION: 11 min 27.665 sec
> *PLANNING*: 06 min 30.337 sec
> QUEUED: Not Available
> EXECUTION: 04 min 57.328 sec
> ```

What can I do to improve performance? Do I need to change the storage or compression on the json files to improve the read performance?

Comment: Can you try merging the json file and see how it performs ? Count of  163,783 json files seems to be Small Files Problem in Hadoop. You can merge files as in example - https://drill.apache.org/docs/json-data-model/#ticket_sales.json-contents.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

As noted that is large number of files for such a small data set. I typically find Drill to work best with files in the 100-200MB range, pending overall data set size and use case. Then it normally can process at around 100-200MB/s per core for JSON pending the complexity of the JSON and queries, and speed of the system.

You can potentially use Drill to create the smaller set of files on the data set, try doing a CTAS on the current data set and set the format to JSON. Also setting store.json.writer.uglify to true will write more compact JSON with less whitespace (but less human readable). Or simple merge the current files to around 100-200MB files with another tool.

count(*) on JSON is not as simple as it sounds. If you are trying to understand the total number of records you can pick a field that is present in all records and then do a count on that field specifically. If you need to do a nested operation like flatten, you can still pick a field that will be present in all records. I found it to be better and more reliable than a simple count(*) on JSON data.